# The convergence or divergence of the series formed by the minimum values of two monotonically decreasing divergent series of positive terms.

Tags: convergence-divergence

Given two sequences $\{a_n \}$ and $\{b_n \}$ that are both monotonically decreasing sequences of positive terms, and the series $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ both diverge, where $c_n=\min(a_n, b_n)$, can we determine the convergence or divergence of the series $\sum c_n$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Would this answer your question? (from AoPS) https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1922847p13188000